# getchar function working differently after Ubuntu 19.04 update?

Tags: nasm, ubuntu-19.04

I am writing a program using both Assembly and c++ to collect user-inputted data. In my c++ file, I read in user numbers with a `cin` loop:

```
    while (cin >> input)
    {
       myArray.push_back(input);
    }

    cin.clear();
```

The user is also told to type `CTRL-D` when finished. In my linked Assembly file I ask the user `Are these numbers correct (y/n)?`

Previously before updating to Ubuntu 19.04, I would do `cin.clear()` as noted above after reading in the inputs so when I performed `call getchar` back in my Assembly file, I could actually receive input from the user. However, after updating Ubuntu, my program only outputs the question if the numbers are correct and does not read in `’y/n‘`.

I have attempted `cin.ignore()` as well after my cin loop but that does not seem to fix my issue. I can only assume that `call getchar` in my Assembly file is reading some newline character rather than taking in a user input, but no matter the fixes I have found online, nothing seems to accept it.

For further clarification I am compiling/linking with g++ in my terminal and assembling with nasm. I can provide further code if needed. In Assembly, I am simply doing:

```
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, correctnumbersprompt ;This holds the string asking y/n
    call printf
    call getchar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fix.

To clear the stream state properly, I had to clear it from both my C++ file with `cin.clear();` and within my Assembly file, I cleared the stream by performing:

```
extern stdin
extern clearerr

mov rax, 0
mov rdi, [stdin]
call clearerr
```

This made it so I could successfully perform `call getchar` to grab user input after using `CTRL+D` to end an input stream.